# Adding text onto image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I currently have code which contains a form that produces a value whenever text is submitted, the value appears on the webpage. My issue is that once submitted, I would like for the value to appear on an image above the text field..

Here is my javascript code

```
var list = document.querySelector('ul');
  var input = document.querySelector('input');
  var button = document.querySelector('button');
  button.onclick = function() {
    var myItem = input.value;
    input.value = '';
    var listItem = document.createElement('li');
    var listText = document.createElement('span');
    var listBtn = document.createElement('button');
    listItem.appendChild(listText);
    listText.textContent = myItem;
    listItem.appendChild(listBtn);
    listBtn.textContent = 'Delete';
    list.appendChild(listItem);
    listBtn.onclick = function(e) {
      list.removeChild(listItem);
    }
    input.focus();
  }
```

Comment: A working code snippet would be helpful here. One way here would be to use `position: absolute;` for the text to place it over top of the image you are using.

Comment: Where is that image positioned? share more code so we could help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can checkout this link they have an example where you can for example position a text in the center of an image https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_image_text_center.

```
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
}

img { 
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

<div class="container">
  <img src="img_5terre_wide.jpg" alt="Cinque Terre" width="1000" height="300">
  <div class="center">Centered</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Be more specific while asking and share some screenshots what you want. In this case I would say you can use Position Absolute in order to overlay text on the image.

```
 .text_div{
    position:absolute;
    top:10%;
    left:30%;
 }
```

Comment: My score is not high enough to post images... thanks anyway.

Comment: You'll need more that `position:absolute`. You'll need to specify where the `top` and possibly `left` should be. It also depends on the HTML structure. To give an actual answer, we need to see the HTML.